# Magento2: How to use block from another module in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-page

I've one third party extension which is adding addthis block on few pages.

I want to add addthis block on product page too.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/La‌​yout/etc/page_config‌​uration.xsd"> 
   <body> 
          <referenceContainer name="content"> <block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Social\AddThis" name="addthis.js.init.new" template="Magefan_Blog::addthis-js.phtml" after="product.info.details" /> </referenceContainer> 
     </body> 
</page>
```

So I'm thinking to use the same block from that third party module. I've added that block definition in catalog_product_view.xml file in my custom module. But its not working. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please add catalog_product_view.xml which you have added for it.

Comment: <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      
    <body>
        

        
        <referenceContainer name="content">
   
   <block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Social\AddThis" name="addthis.js.init.new" template="Magefan_Blog::addthis-js.phtml" after="product.info.details" />
         
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>

Comment: Do not add it in comment, add it in your question.

Comment: Ok. Any fix on this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove unwanted character `;` from `<page ..` tag,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/La‌​yout/etc/page_config‌​uration.xsd"> 
   <body> 
      <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Social\AddThis" name="addthis.js.init.new" template="Magefan_Blog::addthis-js.phtml" after="product.info.details" />
      </referenceContainer> 
    </body> 
</page>
```

try this

Comment: Hey, that might be added by mistake. There is no semicolon in my code.

Comment: check this `xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; ` also remove `layout="1column"`

Comment: Ok. I've removed that but still not working.

Comment: check `phtml` file path in your custom extension.

Comment: Anyways, I've created my own block for that. Thank you for your answers.